# $u_{xy}=u_x+u_y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This equation is bugging me for a while now. It seems pretty simple but what is the general solution?

There are ways to find solutions like
$u(x,y)=Ae^{Bx+\frac{B}{1-B}y}+C(x-y)+D$
But I wonder if there is a way to represent all the solutions.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u(x,y)=v(\xi,\eta)$, where $\xi=x+y$ and $\eta=x-y$; then
$$
u_{xy}=u_x+u_y \implies v_{\xi\xi}-v_{\eta\eta}=2v_{\xi}. \tag{1}
$$
Next, substitute $v=e^{\xi}w$ in $(1)$ and obtain
$$
w_{\eta\eta}-w_{\xi\xi}+w=0. \tag{2}
$$
Equation $(2)$ is an instance of the [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation). Its general solution can be obtained using the Fourier transform, and is given by
$$
w(\xi,\eta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[A(k)e^{ik\xi+i\omega_k\eta}+B(k)e^{ik\xi-i\omega_k\eta}\right]dk, \tag{3}
$$
where $\omega_k=\sqrt{k^2+1}$.

Comment: With $w_{\eta\eta}-w_{\xi\xi}+w=0$ separation of variables can be used.

Comment: With an unbounded domain, you will have an uncountable set of feasible separation constants which is equivalent to the Fourier transform.

Comment: If $(1)$ is correct, then $v_{\xi}=(e^{\xi}w)_{\xi}=e^{\xi}(w_{\xi}+w)$, $v_{\xi\xi}=e^{\xi}(w_{\xi\xi}+2w_{\xi}+w)$, and $v_{\eta\eta}=e^{\xi}w_{\eta\eta}$, hence $$(1)\implies e^{\xi}(w_{\xi\xi}+2w_{\xi}+w-w_{\eta\eta})=2e^{\xi}(w_{\xi}+w)\implies w_{\xi\xi}-w_{\eta\eta}=w \implies (2).$$

Comment: Yes you are right